# Check if on img click the hyperlink is activated (nigthwatch.js)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, nightwatch.js, uitest

In a UI test in `nigthwatch.js` I want to check if, when an image is clicked, the page goes to a different page, for example **google.com**.

HTML:

```
 <a id= "logoLink" href="https://google.com">
    <img src="logo.png" height=20% width=20%> 
 </a>
```

**How do I write a UI test for that in `nigthwatch.js` ?**

Comment: click on the image and check for page location